# Can we enable Networking in single user mode of Linux?

Tags: rhel, runlevel

Can we enable Networking in single user mode of Linux ? 
If Yes then how ?

Comment: What version of RedHat are you running and what system init framework is running on it (`systemd`, `upstart` etc.)?

Comment: rhel7 is my current linux distribution

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can enable networking from single user mode.  However, without knowing which Linux distribution and version and your skill level, it is difficult to provide precise instructions.

Comment: The tag says "rhel".

Comment: There have been many versions (releases)  of RHEL of the years.  Some used SysV init mechanism, some used upstart, current version uses systemd.   More information is therefore  required.

Comment: Ah, that is correct.